# How to Group By on Static Data having UNION in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to do a `SELECT` with `UNION` in Microsoft SQL Server where SQL statement has static string columns on which I would like to do a `Group By`. I am getting this error:

> [Code: 207, SQL State: S0001] Invalid column name 'chrg_tx'. [Script position: 221 - 237]

The same SQL works in other RDBMS like INFORMIX.

Here is my SQL

```
SELECT 
    '' AS chrg_tx, 
    SUM(gross_after_discount) gross, 
    SUM(tax) tax, 
    SUM(net) net
FROM 
    invce_line_item 
WHERE 
    ctry_cd = 'US' 
    AND lcl_btch_id = '2021-11-1214:49:20.838.EN'
    AND invce_no = 'INV000001' 
    AND tax != 0 
    AND insr = 0 
GROUP BY 
    chrg_tx

UNION

SELECT 
    'ASSURANCE' AS chrg_tx,
    SUM(insr + insr_dsct) gross,
    SUM(insr_tax) tax, 
    SUM(net_insr) net
FROM 
    invce_line_item 
WHERE 
    ctry_cd = 'US' 
    AND lcl_btch_id = '2021-11-1214:49:20.838.EN'
    AND invce_no = 'INV000001' 
    AND insr != 0 
GROUP BY 
    chrg_tx
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY chrg_tx`, given that this column/alias is just a constant?

Comment: You can't use the alias in the `GROUP BY`. In your query `chrg_tx` is just constant string. You don't need to `GROUP BY` that at all. Remove the `GROUP BY chrg_tx` and it will work

Comment: Since Migration happening from another server, we wanted to keep OLD SQL as is, Thanks, You are right, Let me give a try.

Comment: Thanks Tim and Squirrel. It works. Appreciate your time.

Comment: And change `UNION` to `UNION ALL` since you obviously have no need for duplicate removal. That will make your query more efficient. By default you should choose UNION ALL since duplicate removal is a rare need (and often that need is a sign of logic flaws in the related queries).